# No echo command?

Tags: command-line, linux, linux-ubuntu, echo

I tried doing the following command on a new install of Ubuntu and got a "Sorry, command not supported on this version message":

```
:echo @%
```

How could any version of vim not support echo? The reported version is 7.4 Small version without GUI.

Comment: Go to command line. Press ctrl and R and then %. Did you see the file name inserted?

Comment: @SibiCoder That's what I did as a workaround until I was able to install the full version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu comes packaged with a tiny version of vim. It is nearly vi. To install the *real* version of vim, run

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Personally, I prefer:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

since this comes with things like python and clipboard support, and gvim, but installing the default vim version should be enough to get echo working.

I don't remember *exactly* what the difference between the two is, and I don't have Ubuntu set up so I can't test it right now, but `apt-get install vim` should come with the sane defaults and `apt-get install vim-gnome` should get you the full features.

Comment: Worth noting is that installing vim-gnome _also_ gives you a full-featured _console_ vim. It is a somewhat puzzling and misleading package name for someone looking for a console vim that's not been gimped.

Answer (score 4):

you got a small version of Vim installed. That means, many functions are not supported, you can read about, what each flavor supports at `:h +feature-list` ([link](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#+feature-list)).

So among the features not supported are multibyte, eval (plugins), diff, folding and quickfix.

The easiest solution to get a better full-working Vim is to install vim-gtk (full version with GTK Gui), vim-nox (full version without gui support) or vim-gnome (full version with Gnome Support)

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command depends on the `eval` feature.  The `eval` faeture is compiled in only in models `normal` and larger.